# Sharing information between screens in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uipickerview

I have UITabBarController, containing 2 screens - A,B.
I also have a strings array - strArr in my application delegate (this array is a global variable).

Screen A changes strArr.
Screen B contains UIPickerView that displays the values from strArr.

The problem:
When I see screen B, I can see the updated values from the strArr array in the picker. BUT, after I'm changing the values of strArr in Screen A, switching to screen B and watching the spinner, I still see the old values, and the app crashes when I'm selecting non-existing anymore item from the picker...

The question (You've probably already know what I'm about to ask..):
How can I display the updated values in the picker that located on screen B?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If part of your data model changes and the rest of your app needs to know about it, you can use [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) or [notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html).

Comment: Solved it in another way (global variables) but thanks for introducing me the Key-Value Coding, which could take place as a solution as well.